# How to unzip file using chilkat in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, chilkat

How unzip file using chilkat?
I have problem to openzip(filepath) using vb.net?

my code

```
Dim zip As New Chilkat.zip()
Dim success As Boolean
success = zip.Openzip(ZipTargetFile)
If (success <> True) Then
  MessageBox1("File can't open")
  Exit Sub
End If
```

How to open zip file using chilkat. can someone help me?

Comment: Uhm, are you sure that 'Exit Sub' is on right prosition?

Comment: According http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vbnetZipRef.html you have to use the method zip.Unzip() or zip.Extract(). That page mentioned you need a path to the zip file as parameter.

Comment: exit sub if the file can't open the zip file. i thik it on rigt position..

Comment: I used unzip to extract the zip file.. I used unrar for .rar file and it succesfull.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Unzip` instead of `Openzip` should work. Additionally, your code is way too complicated. It should be done as follows:

```
Dim zip As New Chilkat.Zip()
Dim success As Boolean = zip.Unzip(ZipTargetFile)

If Not success Then
    MessageBox1("File can't open")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: i already done like that but i just give the same result.. here is my code <br>

Comment: @user714435 Can you open the Zip file manually? Is it perhaps password encrypted? Alternatively perhaps the library simply cannot cope with this particular zip archive because it uses an algorithm not supported by the library.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to work, I needed to use both the OpenZip and Unzip functions (plus CloseZip in order to archive the file after unzipping if not encapsulated in a `using` statement).

```
Zip zipHelper = new Zip();
zipHelper.OpenZip(fileInfo.FullName);
zipHelper.Unzip(fileInfo.DirectoryName);
zipHelper.CloseZip();
```